# prevent order-only prerequisite from being rebuilt if out of date

Tags: makefile

A collegue just came across this, and I thought I'd ask if there's any neat solution to the following problem:  I have a GNU makefile:

```
a: | b
    touch $@
b:c
    touch $@
c:
    touch $@
```

Then I run:

```
~/tmp> make a
touch c
touch b
touch a
~/tmp> make a
make: `a' is up to date.
~/tmp> touch b
~/tmp> make a
make: `a' is up to date.
~/tmp> touch c
~/tmp> make a
touch b
```

It rebuilds `b` but not `a` if I touch `c`.   Is there a way to NOT rebuild `b` if it is being invoked by an order-only prerequisite?  ( in the real-life case `b` is a file with hundreds of dependencies, which may not be around when `make a` is invoked.   I can't make `b`'s prerequisites be order-only as that would break `make b`)

Comment: Good question. Not that I know of. I don't think the order-only relationship can generally be understood to have these semantics but having a prerequisite with these semantics could certainly be a useful thing to have.

Comment: Ok, thanks.  Given the lack of responses, I'll take it it's not possible (I could add a line in the recipe to explicitly call `make b` if b doesn't exist, but that seems hackish to me)

Comment: How does `b` exist without its prerequisites in a way that make doesn't understand (akin to how it handles missing intermediates)? Or is the issue less that they don't exist and more that they may have changed but you don't actually care about redoing b for that? (You could do a does-b-exist test with wildcard and only add the order-only prereq to `a` when it doesn't too.)

Comment: `b` is third party software.  `b` is configured and built for the target architecture, and the architecture is appended to its name.   Target `a` packages it, but is not run until much later.   The problem is that we want to build multiple versions of b -- one for each architecture, and then package them all into one bundle (so b.mips, b.arm, etc).  If you build `b.arm` followed by `b.mips`, then `b.arm`'s dependencies become out of date.  `a` is dependent on `b.mips` and `b.arm` being built, but should not rebuild them based on timestamps.

Comment: Ah. I see. Yeah, that's a bit tricky. Copies of the source per-target would "solve" that problem but is pretty ugly. The make-parse-time detection of prerequisite with `$(wildcard)` would probably work here if you wanted to bother with that. Alternatively putting it in the recipe or in a driver shell/etc. script would work too.

Comment: "If you build b.arm followed by b.mips, then b.arm's dependencies become out of date"

I don't understand why. BTW are `b.arm` and `b.mips` built by two separate `make ARCH=arm` invocations?

Comment: @MarcH E.g. some object files which `b` depends on are regenerated (different compiler switches, maybe some different assembler part) making them younger than `b`. This is most likely a consequence of the violation of [Paul's rule #2](http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/rules-of-makefiles/) where the build process of the external software always only produces a platform-anonymous output file.

Answer (score 2):

The behavior is fully correct. You instructed `make` to ignore the tight dependency between `a` and `b` and depend only on `b` presence. Whilst `a` and `c` share a **date dependency**.

This is the difference between `a: b` and `a: | b`.

---

If one wants to investigate that case (or other `make` *magic* :) ):

Try the following, you'll see that `make` is keen and tells you what it is doing for `b` target:

```
% touch b
% LANG=C make -rd | awk '/^Considering/,/^$/ {print}'
Considering target file `a'.
  Considering target file `b'.
    Considering target file `c'.
     Finished prerequisites of target file `c'.
    No need to remake target `c'.
   Finished prerequisites of target file `b'.
   Prerequisite `c' is older than target `b'.
  No need to remake target `b'.
 Finished prerequisites of target file `a'.
 Prerequisite `b' is order-only for target `a'.      <--- "order-only"
No need to remake target `a'.
```

Now, add a tight dependency:

```
% echo "a:b" >> Makefile
```

And compare results:

```
% touch b
% LANG=C make -rd | awk '/^Considering/,/^$/ {print}'
Considering target file 'a'.
  Considering target file 'b'.
    Considering target file 'c'.
     Finished prerequisites of target file 'c'.
    No need to remake target 'c'.
   Finished prerequisites of target file 'b'.
   Prerequisite 'c' is older than target 'b'.
  No need to remake target 'b'.
  Pruning file 'b'.
 Finished prerequisites of target file 'a'.
 Prerequisite 'b' is order-only for target 'a'.
 Prerequisite 'b' is newer than target 'a'.          <--- additional "date dependency"
Must remake target 'a'.
touch a                                              <--- 'a' is rebuilt
Putting child 0x1b09ec0 (a) PID 5940 on the chain.
Live child 0x1b09ec0 (a) PID 5940 
Reaping winning child 0x1b09ec0 PID 5940 
Removing child 0x1b09ec0 PID 5940 from chain.
Successfully remade target file 'a'.
```

I used `make -r` (no implicit rules) as this example doesn't use them and it's *boring* to read.

Comment: I understand why it happens, but I was wondering if there was a way around it -- that is, when building a, only remake b if it doesn't exist yet.   I ended up adding the line: `[ -e b ] || $(MAKE) b`  as the first line of the recipe.

Comment: @John, the correct behavior is the one you expect "when building a, only remake b if it doesn't exist yet". If that's not the case, it is either an issue of your Makefile (your file) or `make` tool. Please check tabulations.

Comment: I get the described behavior on all versions of gnu make I've tested with (3.81, plus several cross compile versions).   If I do `touch a; touch b; touch c; make a` then it will always rebuild `b` because `c` is newer than `b`... (though it does not rebuild `a`).

Comment: Sorry, the cross-compile machine is running 3.82, and demonstrates the same behaviour

Answer (score 0):

Comments aside, your problem statement is extremely generic, it's very far from describing an actual use case. This makes it very short and easy to read and understand. On the other hand, understanding and solving or working around your *particular* problem is more uncertain.

I've seen your exact same, generic problem statement apply to this other use case:

```
nimble_exe: nimble_srcs | big_lib
    touch $@

big_lib: biglib_many_sources_and_headers
    touch $@
    sleep 1 # simulate a long [no-op] build time

biglib_many_sources_and_headers
    touch $@
```

This code means: "build big_lib when it's missing for nimble_exe, but don't care when it's out of date" which superficially matches the definition of an "order-only dependency" and even [used to match ninja's behavior until 2011](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ninja-build/lSiVYhWEIyM)

Unfortunately, if anyone changes anything in the `biglib_many_sources_and_headers`, `make nimble_exe` rebuilds `big_lib` but **not** `nimble_exe`! This shows that "order-only dependencies" were simply not designed for that use case. So I recommend this instead:

```
nimble_exe: nimble_srcs
    test -e big_lib || $(MAKE) big_lib
    touch $@
```